# How to pull data from another branch

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and I need to pull some files from another branch.
The repository has 3 branches and I need to pull from branch other than the master branch. How do I do that? Please give the answer in an easy way possible.

I tried using git checkout but it didn't work

Comment: How colloquially do you use the term "pull" here? What do you want to achieve? I'm asking because it's a bit odd to talk about "pulling files" in git, so I 'm suspecting a possible confusion on the terms.

Answer (score 1):

You are in master branch. If you want to pull three files: file1, file2, file3 from another branch say, BranchA, then you have to use below command:

```
git checkout BranchA -- /pathTofile1
git checkout BranchA -- /pathTofile2 
git checkout BranchA -- /PathTofile3
```

Comment: Wow this is the answer the OP wanted. I'll use it sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First fetch all the branches.

`git fetch`

Now checkout the branch you want.

`git checkout -b branch_name`

This will create a local branch with checkout of branch_name.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command to clone your branch

```
 git fetch
 git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

You can also refer to this [link](https://coderwall.com/p/y7hf6w/how-to-clone-a-specific-branch-in-git)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Sourcetree for pulling or merging branch for doing that. You can feel more comfortable while you are learning git.

In the Sourcetree, it will show you that you must pull or merge the branch.